# DB2 UTF-8 encoding: Umlaut to CHAR(1)?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, db2

What does "CHAR(1)" in a UTF-8 encoded DB2 database mean?

Can I insert a special character (e.g. one that takes 2 octets in UTF-8) into a column of CHAR(1)?

Or does CHAR(1) in UTF-8 always mean, that it has capacity for one byte / octet, i.e. such that inserting an Umlaut into it will fail ?

I read through this interesting [developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0506chong/) article, but it's going to deep for my simple question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. :)

DB2 introduced `code units` to help with designing string-typed columns that are based on number of characters and not number of bytes. The [`CREATE TABLE`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) statement has an overview of data types and also explains `CHAR` and `VARCHAR`. If number of characters is used, DB2 is assuming the worst case - 4 bytes/octets per character - for length computations.

The database configuration [`string_units`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0060936.html) determines whether by default the number of characters (`CODEUNITS32`) or the number of bytes (`SYSTEM`) is considered.

Coming back to your question: If you did not specify anything, inserting a special character that needs 2 octets into a CHAR(1) will likely fail. If CODEUNITS32 was specified, then it will succeed.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to answer the question. Can you please add information when this has been introduced? In the documentation code units appear with v10.5.0 ...

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can use the drop-down in the docs to switch to other versions. `string_units` is only available for 10.5 and up.

Comment: And just out of curiosity: How was this done before? Fixing the codepage at CREATE TABLE such that 8bit were always enough ?

Comment: No, UTF-8 and other Unicode codepages are supported since a long time. UTF-8 is the default codepage since IMHO V9.5. Globalization / i18n requires some thoughts and good planning...