# column definition for varchar(n) CHAR in DB2 z/OS using UTF-8?

Tags: db2, ddl, db2-zos

I'm looking for a way to define a column for holding an UTF-8 String with a maximum length of n characters (not bytes) in DB2 for z/OS.
To my knowledge [code_units](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41934320) are available only in DB2 LUW.

Answer (score 0):

Help yourself by studying the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/char/src/tpc/db2z_storeunicodedata.html), because there are several aspects to consider before making your choice, this is particularly important with mainframes.

Be sure to talk with your DBA for Z/OS and more experienced people at your site , as there may be local practices and procedures that will determine exactly how you do things.

Comment: We are migrating an existing application from Oracle, so we unfortunately don't have a choice but UTF-8 fixed-width columns.